# selenium not being able to find element unless i move my mouse over to that element

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC to automate some third party site and facing some issue with upload file button.

That the button is present on the page but Selenium is unable to find and click that element. I tried to wait for that element to be present on the page so after going down the issue I came to know that Selenium will find that element if I move my mouse over that button manually while I am waiting for that element.

Here is my code snippet.

```
public void testBox() throws Exception{
    selenium.setTimeout("10000000000");
    selenium.open("/files");
    selenium.click("id=login_button_credentials");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("150000");
    while(!selenium.isElementPresent("id=upload_split_arrow")) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }

    selenium.click("id=upload_split_arrow");
    while(!selenium.isElementPresent("id=upload_file1")) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }

    selenium.click("id=upload_file1");
    Thread.sleep(10000000);
}
```

Can anyone suggest some workaround for that?

Comment: Don't open the file upload control, just send the path of the file to the element.

Comment: Hi arran That is what i am doing instead of clicking it i am using selenium.type("id=upload_file1","D:\\Downloads\\testcases\\testcases\\SalesforceAccounts.java");                                                  i am using above type command but this is not an issue issue is selenium is not being able to find that element and as soon as i move my mouse to that element it finds it.

Answer (score 0):

use "focus" before using "click" command.
It may serve the purpose.

```
    selenium.focus("id=upload_file1");
    selenium.click("id=upload_file1");
```

Comment: Hi HemChe even for focusing it should be able to find that button first that it does not find untill i manually move my mouse over that button.

Comment: even on selenium.focus i get element not found exception